# Issue WSL commands and read returned value from C#

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am writing a code to execute some commands against wsl, parsing and reading the returned value is important.

Project is a .net core console app 3.1

wsl2 is enabled on the system

for example, listing all the available wsl images on my local machine i am using a snippet found in an answer provided in another "kind of related" SO post.

```
using (var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            })
            {
                proc.Start();
                proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("wsl --list");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                proc.StandardInput.Flush();
                proc.StandardInput.Close();
                proc.WaitForExit(5000);
                var c = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(c);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

now the expected output should be

[image]

what i am getting is

[image]

if i inspect using breakpoint i get this in "var c"

[image]

Ideally i want to be able to have a list that contains the 2 dockers items inside C#, changing the wait time didn't help.

Comment: Why do you run with `Process.start()` the executable `cmd.exe` (hopefully found first in Windows system directory) instead of directly `wsl.exe`? It does not make a difference for function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) used by C# method `Process.start()` which name the executable has as long as being found on starting the executable without its full qualified file name. `cmd.exe` uses also `CreateProcess` to run `wsl.exe`.

Comment: See also [Environment.SystemDirectory Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.systemdirectory) and please read also the Microsoft documentation for [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Comment: @Mofi i tried that as well but var c was empty i ran wsl.exe instead of cmd and just passed --list/ wsl --list

Comment: i don't think the issue is in running cmd/wsl i can run both successfully however the output is unusable in any sense, if i do an echo instead of wsl --list it works just fine

Comment: However, `wsl.exe` is a full Unicode aware application which outputs data in Unicode with [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Little Endian.`cmd.exe` uses by default a different [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) with just one by per character (called ANSI encoding) using an OEM code page depending on country configured for the used user account. So it is really better to run `wsl.exe` directly and of course interpret the output text as Unicode text.

Comment: that escaped my mind i will look into that.

Comment: You just need to use the [Encoding class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding) to convert the UTF-16 LE text captured from `wsl.exe` output to the encoding you want to use for the output of captured text.

Answer (score 0):

in the ProcessStartInfo you have to set

```
StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
```

for direct call of wsl use additionally:

```
FileName = @"wsl.exe";
Arguments = @"-l -v";
```